# Ios default icon for open view from list

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In every ios app you can have a list that contains elements with subelements.
Tapping on the element will open a new page and you can usually press back to return.
This is indicated with a grey ">" symbol on the right.
Is this symbol downloadable somewhere? I know i can just type a > but it doesn't look exactly like the default icon used by ios.

I'm using Xamarin dialog and a standard RootElement embedded as a list item looks exactly like the default ios but i need to customize it with an icon placed left of the text(which is no problem except that i now lose the default > icon).
Googling for ios system icons, ios default icons and ios sdk did not yield the wanted result. I'm hoping that these icons are somewhere embedded on the device.
I hope you guys can help me out, thanks !

Comment: maybe, you need iOS GUI PSD to get the icon you want,just googling

Comment: That indeed contains the IOS 7 icon but what if i have to support IOS 6 as well? When IOS 8 comes i have to change it again as well. Is there no way to pull the icon from the device style it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to access a UIImage instance of the chevron during run time. Most likely there is private API for this, but I am not aware of it, and since it's private you are not allowed to use it anyway.

You could probably instantiate a cell that has the disclosure indicator as accessoryType and walk the view hierarchy to find it. But that will break easily, so don't do it.

The best way is to add an image and update it with every new iOS release.
There's the [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor) which basically gets you every piece of artwork that is used in iOS.
The artwork you are looking for should be named UITableNext. (at least that's the name in iOS6, I don't have an extracted archive of iOS7 yet)

Strictly speaking you are violating Apples rules and their copyright if you use their artwork without Apples written consent. 
As far as I know this has never been enforced, and lots of people do it, but it's good to keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, if extracting and updating is the way i should go then golly that way i shall go. Still find it a bit weird coming from the design heavy product ios but hey i'll live :)